# How to overcome SSL protocol version error in Paid Membership Pro?

Tags: wordpress, payment-gateway, paypal

I am using paid membership pro plugin for setting up membership website in WordPress. I have selected "Pay By Check" payment gateway and it work fine.

But, when i change payment gateway to "Paypal Express" and follow process to payment, it throw `methodName_ failed: Unsupported SSL protocol version`.
I am stucked with this since 2 days, but does not found proper solution.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Please add below hook in function.php It's TLS version issue. Your server may not support the TLS 1.

```
function my_http_api_curl($handle) {
 curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1 ); 
}
add_action('http_api_curl', 'my_http_api_curl')
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your SSL version?

PayPal Express requires you are running OpenSSL/1.0.1 or higher, NSS/3.15.1 or higher

Comment: Domain is not SSL.